# Syntax Error when adding ERB link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

In the code block below everything worked fine until I added the two 'link_to' lines at the bottom. I am roughly following [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and am at the end of part 5.11

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <li>
    <%= post.player1 %>
    <%= post.player2 %>
    <br>
    <%= post.text %>
    <%= link_to 'View' post_path(post) %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit' edit_post_path(post) %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

This is the error message:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' ...pend=( link_to 'View' post_path(post) );@output_buffer.safe_... ... ^
```

Comment: The examples in the guide all have a comma after the string in `link_to`. Why didn't you copy that?

Comment: ruby making us forget opening/closing circular brackets for functions,  can future ruby become a bit more smart for lazy people like us

Comment: @Barmar I don't like to copy and paste code from tutorials. It helps me learn if I type it myself. Lesson learned! Won't happen again.

Comment: I don't like people to just copy and paste. But you should read them and UNDERSTAND what they're doing. In most programming languages, parameters are separated by commas.

Answer (score 3):

Add commas between the arguments:

```
<%= link_to 'View', post_path(post) %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>
```

Comment: To add to this, you'll be best looking at the [`link_to` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Comment: @infused Wow can't believe I missed that. Thanks for pointing that out.